# Is it possible to add a new location block inside kong proxy server?

Tags: nginx, kong, openresty

I have an use-case where for a particular request with path say /test-abc, i want the request to go to S3 rather than kong and all requests with path other than /test-abc should flow to kong gateway. I tried adding the location block in nginx-kong.conf as below, But I don't see requests going to s3. Can someone please help me understand what I'm missing here?

```
# Kong's Proxy server block
  server {
    server_name kong;

    # any contents until the location / block
    ...


    location / {
      
      ...
    }

    location  /test-abc {
        proxy_pass <s3-url-here>
        add_header  'content-type' 'application/json';
        add_header  'cache-control' 'public, max-age=0';
        add_header  'vary' 'Accept-Encoding';
        add_header  'accept-ranges' 'bytes';
        charset UTF-8;
        default_type application/json;
    }
  }
```